# Can't Mass Assign Protected Attributes Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to create a `teacher` table which has a column in it called 'teacher_type_id' i.e. it's a foreign key which is connected to the `teacherType` table which has three rows, namely 1 => Tutor, 2 => Module Leader and 3 => Lecturer.

My `schema.rb` file has the following information in it:

```
create_table "teacher_types", :force => true do |t|
 t.string   "title"
 t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
 t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end

create_table "teachers", :force => true do |t|
 t.integer  "teacherType_id"
 t.string   "firstName"
 t.string   "lastName"
 t.datetime "created_at",     :null => false
 t.datetime "updated_at",     :null => false
end

add_index "teachers", ["teacherType_id"], :name => "index_teachers_on_teacherType_id"
```

The `teacher_typ.rb` file looks like this:

```
class TeacherType < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :teachers
 attr_accessible :title, :teacher_type_id   (Also tried :teacherType_id)
end
```

And my `teacher.rb` file looks like this:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :teacherType
  attr_accessible :firstName, :lastName
end
```

However, now when I go to my `localhost:3000/teacher/new` and try to create a new teacher using either "1" or "Tutor" as the TeacherType, however when i submit the form, I always get the same error, which is:

**`ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in TeachersController#create`**

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: teacherType_id
Rails.root: /Users/omar/rails_projects/attendance

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/teachers_controller.rb:43:in `new'
app/controllers/teachers_controller.rb:43:in `create'
```

**`Request`**

```
Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"NEJf3bISJsidStVyfdRns0oZ7JzSZ8RqqZSAWgL9hz8=",
 "teacher"=>{"teacherType_id"=>"Tutor",
 "firstName"=>"Jack",
 "lastName"=>"Sparrow"},
 "commit"=>"Create Teacher"}`
```

Any ideas why that could be? I had a look at the `attr_accessible` but still to no avail

Comment: Why is the attr accessible in teacher type?

Comment: Was playing around with the `attr_accessible` as I read on various forums and questions answered that this solved it. But it doesn't really

Comment: But the attr is in teacher, not teacher type.

Comment: Yeah, doesn't that mean that TeacherType is making the teacher_type_id attritube accessible to other models...? Abitike declaring a public variable i thought.... Or am I totally wrong in my thinking

Comment: No, it means the model it's declared in is allowing mass-assignment of that attribute--and that apneadiving's answer works should clarify it even further. Think about it--you wouldn't want to set a teacherType's ID from a form, teacherTypes already *have* an ID.

Comment: So does that mean it is restricted to only the teacherType_id's which exist i.e. 1,2 and 3?
Because when i put 4 in, it uses that....

Comment: No, accessible means it can be set, there's no consistency checking on the rails side.

Comment: Isn't there a way to just display a dropdown list of the available TeacherType_id, but instead of displaying the ID, display the :title?

Comment: Yes, using normal Rails mechanisms. That's a different question, though.

Comment: Shall i open a new question? Or could you just tell me here?

Comment: I'd probably just look at some Rails tutorials/docs/etc first.

Comment: Ok, by the way, I'm using JetBrains RubyMine which has auto-complete functionality. Why is it that there exists `teacher_type_id` and 'teacherType_id`?
I think this will cause me many problems

Comment: Because you broke Rails naming conventions. Rails will generally convert to/from camelCased names to conventional underscore_names but still leave the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Teacher:

```
attr_accessible :firstName, :lastName, :teacherType_id
```

Comment: WTF..... O_o
I been playing around with the teacherType model and the Teacher model, and then out of nowhere the one thing I didn't try works....  Thanks a lot.
By the way, is the :has_many and :has_one correct?
Also, could you just give a brief explanation of why your code works?

Comment: this code works because, the reference field belongs to Teacher (see Rails doc for foreign keys explanation). You could have seen it looking at the params: it was nested in teacher

Answer (score 3):

`teacherType_id` is being assigned a string in the TeachersController#new view, but it's declared as an integer.  Check your view.  Plus I'd avoid using names with mixed cases such as `teacherType_id`...

Comment: but teacherType_id is meant to be the id for the teacherType model. How comes teacher_type_id is also an option?