# Collection_Select not assigning value to my model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

this is a follow up question to [Can't Mass Assign Protected Attributes Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137173/cant-mass-assign-protected-attributes-error)

I'm trying to use a Colleciton_Select so that I can select a TeacherType from a dropdown box, instead of allowing the user to write in the teacherType_id.

`<%= collection_select(:teacherType, :teacherType_id, TeacherType.order('title'), :id, :title, :prompt => true) %>`

However when I select an option from the dropdown menu, it always says that *Teacher was successfully updated*, however nothing changes in the Teacher model.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try this <%= collection_select(:teacher, :teacherType_id, TeacherType.order('title'), :id, :title, :prompt => true) %>

Comment: could you post your params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, I think you are trying to add the `teacherType` to `Teacher` instead of `TeacherType` so you should use

```
<%= collection_select(:teacher, :teacherType_id, TeacherType.order('title'), :id, :title, :prompt => true) %>
```

Now, second point I would like to mention, if you have `has_many` association in one model then you should always have `belongs_to` association in the other.

so modify the association definition in `Teacher` model from

```
 has_one :teacherType
```

to

```
 belongs_to :teacherType
```

One other point, its good practice to have association name as the underscored pluralized form of the associated Model. `Convention over configuration is the way rails applications are supposed to be built.` If in any case you can't have this name, then you must specify the `class_name` attribute to the association definition.

Comment: So whenever I have a `has_many`, I need to have a `belongs_to`? But literally in my head it makes sense saying that TeacherType has many teachers, whilst a Teacher model only has one teacher type associated to it...
Also, I'm not quite sure what you mean with the latter part of your answer, are you referring to my `TeacherType` model? Do you mean that I should have called it `Teacher_Type` instead?

Comment: Actually `belongs_to` association is defined in the model where we keep the foreign/association key. And moreover belonging to a group/type make more sense to me than having a group/type.

Comment: so you're saying having a `belongs_to` instead of a `has_one` relationship, if the other model has a `has_many` relationship with it?

Comment: yes. if the other model has a `has_many` or `has_one`. In both the cases the model should have a `belongs_to` association. This is what my understanding says.

Comment: And in regards to the naming convention which you mentioned, should it be `Teacher_Type` as opposed to `TeaherType`?

Comment: No, model class name should be `TeacherType`, table name should be `teacher_types`, association in Teacher model should be `belongs_to :teacher_type` and the reference key in teachers table should be `teacher_type_id`.